# Using mimetypes.guess_type with email.mime.base.MIMEBase

Tags: python, smtp, mime-types

I'm building SMTP ASCII emails to include attachments and wish to automate the extraction of the "content type" from the proposed attachment using mimetypes.guess_type, then using the result to add it to the mail body by using email.mime.base.MIMEBase.

The problem I'm encountering is that mimetypes.guess_type produces a single string containing the complete content type e.g. image/jpeg. But email.mime.base.MIMEBase expectes 2 seperate variables e.g image and jpeg.

Is there a clean way to do this (i.e. a different def than email.mime.base.MIMEBase) so that I don't have to parse the result from mimetypes.guess_type before being able to use it?

It seems tedious that this would have to be done for these two libraries to work together, so I'm assuming I'm missing another easier way to do it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, such kind of "parsing" is very easy with python. You may try the code below:

```
format, enc = mimetypes.guess_type(filename)
main, sub = format.split('/')
mb = MIMEBase(main, sub)
```

or even more compact:

```
format, enc = mimetypes.guess_type(filename)
mb = MIMEBase(*format.split('/'))
```